# Python - json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, aws-batch

I have a string like below :-

```
'
{
    "data":
        [
            {
                "input": "c",
                "output": "b"
            }
        ],
    "key_1": "",
    "key_2": ""
}
'
```

I am receiving this as environment variable inside python script and trying to load it as dict like below :-

```py
value = os.environ.get("PAYLOAD")
processed_value = json.loads(value)
```

But `json.loads` throws this error :-

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

To share more context, I am passing this variable as environment variable inside AWS Batch with following structure :-

```
payload : '{"data":[{"input": "c","output": "b"}],"key_1": "","key_2": ""}'
```

Post import of the above variable inside container environment, this variable gets modified like listed above.

I have tried various method listed on Stackoverflow but unable to fix this error. Would appreciate any hint on how I can load the data inside my python script as dictionary

Thanks

Comment: try `json.loads(value.strip("'"))` then

Comment: Worked like magic. Thanks